# Neo4j - Date conversion

Tags: date, neo4j, timestamp

I'm using Neo4j database.Neo4j does not have date data type only have timestamp data type.

I need to compare current date with existing date using cql query.

My existing date format is "8/4/2011" that is string.

Then how can I compare it.Any way to use stored procedure [date] while csv bulk data import time.

I used APOC stored procedure but I don't know how compare it.

```
CALL apoc.date.format(timestamp(),"ms","dd.MM.yyyy")
07.07.2016

CALL apoc.date.parse("13.01.1975 19:00","s","dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm")
158871600
```

I expect like this

```
MATCH(dst:Distributor) WHERE dst.DIST_ID = "111137401" WITH dst CALL apoc.date.parse(dst.ENTRY_DATE,'s', 'dd/MM/yyyy') YIELD d SET  dst.ENTRY_DATE = d RETURN dst;
```

Any possibilities please help me...

Comment: That query will replace the `ENTRY_DATE` of that `:Distributor` with a timestamp. If you are able to refactor your data like this, I would recommend doing it to your whole dataset, as it will make things much easier. Are you able to change your data that way?

Answer (score 2):

```
RETURN datetime("2018-06-04T10:58:30.007Z").epochMillis
```

> 1528109910007

Comment: Could you explain how exactly this answers the question to make it more helpful for less experienced users?

Answer (score 0):

Right query is :

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///DST.csv" AS row
CALL apoc.date.parse(toString(row.ENTRY_DATE),"ms","dd-MMM-yy") YIELD value as date CREATE (DST:Distributor {ENTRY_DATE: date })
```